# escaping xml in intellij 14

Tags: intellij-idea, format

in Intellij, I'm looking for a single keystroke method to transform escaped XML to XML and vice versa I've looked at macros with a file find/replace but they are not doing what I need - any suggestions?

e.g.

```
    &lt;Alpha&gt;
    &lt;Beta&gt;3030&lt;/Beta&gt;
    &lt;Beta&gt;3030&lt;/Beta&gt;
&lt;/Alpha&gt;
```

TO

```
<Alpha>
    <Beta>3030</Beta>
    <Beta>3030</Beta>
</Alpha>
```

Comment: What about a two-step search/replace in files? 2 macros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this plugin](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/10/touring-plugins-string-manipulation/), it can do what you want and much more in terms of escaping and string manipulation in general.

You can bind some custom shortcut to *Escape XML* and *Unescape XML* actions. Or you can hit <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> and then <kbd>8</kbd> to escape or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> and then <kbd>9</kbd> to unescape by default.

It's probably not the exact solution you're looking for, but hopefully it will help.